# redirect module function stdout to flask socket

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, stdout, sys

I have a file with a function that counts to 15 in a for loop. I want to redirect the output to a socket.

**test.py**

```
def counttest():
    x = 0
    for x in range(0,15):
        x = x+1
        print("Number: "+ str(x))
        time.sleep(1)
```

I have been able to do this by using the `subprocess` module and using a script like so:
**test_app.py**

```
@sock.route('/echo')
def echo(ws):
    data = ws.receive()
    with subprocess.Popen(['powershell', ".\pingtest.ps1"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1,universal_newlines=True) as process:
            for line in process.stdout:
                line = line.rstrip()
                print(line)
                try:
                    ws.send(line+ "\n")
                except:
                    pass
```

However, I don't think you can use `subprocess` on functions or imported modules. I wanted to use the `multiprocessing` module but they don't seem to have a `stdout`  parameter like the `subprocess` module does.

Is there a way I can send the stdout from a function into a variable constantly? like a forloop that gets updated with realtime stdout from a function?

I tried using the `multiprocessing` module but I am sure that is not how I a suppose to use this:

```
import multiprocessing as Process

@sock.route('/echo')
def echo(ws):
    data = ws.receive()
    testprocess = Process(target=test.counttest())
    ws.send(testprocess)

###THIS FAILS, THE OUTPUT STILL SHOWS IN THE CONSOLE INSTEAD OF GETTING REDIRECTED TO THE SOCKET LIKE THE SUBPROCESS MODULE CAN DO###
```

**If there is no other choice, I could just make my test.counttest() redirect output by forcing the file itself to be ran with subprocess but that is the last choice I want to make**
Example of what I mean:

```
@sock.route('/echo')
def echo(ws):
    data = ws.receive()
    with subprocess.Popen(['python', ".\test.py"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1,universal_newlines=True) as process:
            for line in process.stdout:
                line = line.rstrip()
                print(line)
                try:
                    ws.send(line+ "\n")
                except:
                    pass
```

Comment: Is there a reason you *have* to use stdout? why couldn't it be just string?
This question seems like [the XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Could you explain why you're trying to use stdout?

Comment: Because its a socket.

Comment: I will just make another account again with a VPN and re-ask the question a different way. Thank you for your time.

Comment: First of all, `import muliprocessing as Process` and then having `testprocess = Process(target=test.counttest())` makes absolutely no sense since `Process` is a module. And what is `test.counttest()`? You need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).